# Visual Studios displaying dataColumns by Name instead of Caption

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, dataset, visual-studio-2017

I am using visual studios 2017 to create a new database for my company working from just a bunch of scattered excel files. The newest issue I have come across is naming the DataColumns of the DataSets. 
In visual studios I have edited the properties so that for example the Name of the column is `firstName` and the Caption is **First Name** however when I go to show the `DataSet` as a `DataTable` it will display `firstName` instead of it's caption.

Isn't the caption supposed to be what gets displayed if it gets exposed to the front end? I do have this bit of code that I inserted into the tables file though;

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = clientEmployerDataSet.Clients;
clientsDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Is this having some sort of unintended side effect? I can supply pictures of the properties if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `templatefield` in `gridview` set the header text as **First Name** `HeaderText="First Name"` and set text of `label` as `firstName` like `Text='<% #Eval("firstName") %>'` in `itemtemplate`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblfirstName" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("firstName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```